# Javascript not working? Zurb Foundation accordion issue

Tags: zurb-foundation

So im using zurb foundation framework and something is really weird. On my local server, everything is working fine, however, when I upload the files to my online test server, the accordion drop downs will not work (under courses). Also, my 
's for header do not seem to be loading in the html. The main thing is the accordions, as well as if you load it on mobile phone, the menu drop down will not work. Is this a javascript/jquery issue or is there something else going on?

the site can be viewed at http://www.new.omegadesignla.com which is where I'm hosting for testing.

Comment: it looks like you're adding foundation.min.js AND foundation.accordion.js ...

Comment: i added the accordion after it wasnt working to see if that would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either load each plugin individually, or include foundation.min.js, which automatically loads the Foundation Core and all JavaScript plugins.

```
<script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<!-- or individually -->

<script src="/js/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="/js/foundation.alert.js"></script>
<!-- ... -->
<script src="/js/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="/js/foundation.tab.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have foundation.min.js already in the scripts.. It loads fine on the test server. let me post some of the consol error messages im getting to see if that helps figure it out.

Comment: getting these errors on load in the console:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL modernizr.js:437
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input foundation.min.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function app.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined foundation.accordion.js:4

Comment: you need to load jQuery before all of your other scripts.

Comment: wierd but i wonder why its working on my local server, and how come zurb wouldnt put it like that in the tempalte ?

Comment: still not working, because i moved the jquery script to the top and didn't do anything.

Comment: fixed some files must have been corrupted when i originally uploaded to my server, just re-uploaded the files with successs

Comment: which files?  Yours or the libraries?